# Why is my JSON not camelCase?

Tags: json.net

I'm trying to output Json, with Json.net, by building up a dynamic then calling JsonConvert.Serialize().

The problem is that **my _camelCase contract resolver is not respected, and the output is not camel case**.

```
private JsonSerializerSettings _camelCase = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};

var myObj = new { Prop = "val"};
var myObj2 = new { Prop = "val" };
var objOut = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj, _camelCase);
// {"prop":"val"}
// No problem

// now, a list
var list = new List<object> { myObj, myObj2 };
var listOut = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, _camelCase);
// [{"prop":"val"},{"prop":"val"}]
// no problem

// now, put my list in a dynamic
dynamic myDynamic = new JObject();
myDynamic.List = JArray.FromObject(list);
var dynamicOut = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDynamic, _camelCase);
// {"List":[{"Prop":"val"},{"Prop":"val"}]}
// PROBLEM! _camelCase is not respected
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Ok in case this can be useful for anyone... The serializer settings that count are not those supplied to `JsonConvert.Serialize()`, but those used for the call `JArray.FromObject()`. So I needed to create a serializer with the contract resolver...

```
private JsonSerializerSettings _camelCase = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};
private JsonSerializer _camelCaseSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(_camelCase);
```

...then use it for `FromObject()`...

```
myDynamic.List = JArray.FromObject(list, _camelCaseSerializer );
```

I could also have changed the default settings like this...

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
};
```

... but I lack the courage :-)